# Do *all* non-dividend paying assets have the risk-free instantaneous return rate under the risk-neutral measure?

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, arbitrage, risk-neutral-measure

For simplicity let's consider a 1D BS world. The only source of randomness comes from the Brownian motion dynamics $dB_t$. The risk-free rate is $r$ (one may assume it as constant for the time being). I know that, by virtue of Girsanov's theorem, the Brownian motion under the risk-neutral measure is defined by
$$dB_t^{\Bbb Q} = \lambda dt + dB_t$$
where $\lambda$ is the unique market price of risk, or the so-called Sharpe ratio.

Under the risk-neutral measure, any non-dividend paying stock price process $S_t$ thus follows
$$\frac{dS_t}{S_t} = rdt + \sigma_SdB_t^{\Bbb Q}.$$

However, in Kerry Back's *A Course in Derivative Securities* page 220, the author claimed without a proof that the instantaneous rate of return for a call option on the stock price $C_t$ is also $r$, i.e.
$$\frac{dC_t}{C_t} = rdt + \sigma_C d B_t^{\Bbb Q}$$
where $\sigma_C$ is some stochastic process that we're not interested in. The author make crucial use of the above formula (i.e. the drift of $C_t$ is $rC_tdt$) to derive the BS PDE.

**Question**: is it true that under the risk neutral measure, *any* non-dividend paying asset price $X_t$ must have its instantaneous rate of return equal to $r$? If so, what would be a **rigorous** explanation for this?

---

**Edit**: Antoine is spot on. Under the risk neutral measure, any discounted asset price $Y_t=e^{-rt}X_t$ must be a martingale or equivalently an Ito integral without drift. Hence
$$\frac{dY_t}{Y_t}=\sigma_Y dB_t^{\Bbb Q}.$$
where $\sigma_Y$ can be a quite general stochastic process. On the other hand, by the compounding rule of Ito processes, 
$$\frac{dY_t}{Y_t}=-rdt+\frac{dX_t}{X_t}$$
Therefore it follows
$$\frac{dX_t}{X_t}=rdt+\sigma_Y dB_t^{\Bbb Q}.$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the assumption that the market is **complete**, any discounted contingent claim can be replicated as a **stochastic integral against the discounted stock price**, therefore the discounted contingent claim price is a martingale under the risk neutral measure, or said otherwise the contingent claim price instantaneous rate of return under the risk neutral measure is the risk free rate.

Comment: Oh yes. The discounted asset price must be a m.g.  how could i forget this. Thanks.